# tail function with lapply

Tags: r, lapply, tail

I need to extract last 3 rows of a vector, and store the result in a list, each part of the list containing at the most 3 elements. so after that i can arrange the  results in a matrix.

take this next example:

```
data <- c(130,156,872,23,67,98,104)
```

let's say i need last 3 rows for **every entry of the data frame**

i would need results to be something like this

```
[1]
130
[2]
130 156
[3]
130 156 872
[4]
156 872 23
[5]
872 23 67
```

and so on. thing is: i cant use `lapply` the way i thought i could because is not producing results as expected.

I'm sure this is a rather simple problem, but i can't find a way to solve it, and i'm stuck and super frustrated about it.

[1] and [2] could look something like NA NA 130 for [1] and NA 130 156 for [2].

If i need to be more precise about my question, i'll explain with more details.

Comment: You mentioned a `data.frame` but then your `data` object is a numeric vector.

Comment: **How** did you try using `lapply`?

Comment: And what results did you get when you used `lapply`.

Comment: i'm sorry, you're right. that's not a data frame, my input is a vector.
i tried
result <- lapply(data,tail,3)

that's obviosuly not working. I want results summarized the way they are in the opening thread.

Comment: … so you **didn’t** actually use `tail`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `lapply` to go through the indices along `data` and subset three consecutive elements at one time

```
lapply(1:length(data), function(i) data[max(1, (i-2)):i])
#[[1]]
#[1] 130

#[[2]]
#[1] 130 156

#[[3]]
#[1] 130 156 872

#[[4]]
#[1] 156 872  23

#[[5]]
#[1] 872  23  67

#[[6]]
#[1] 23 67 98

#[[7]]
#[1]  67  98 104
```

Comment: with tail: `lapply(seq_along(data), function(x) tail(data[1:x] , n = 3))`

Comment: thank you both!! both solutions work perfectly. 3 days stuck with this and 10 minutes here and solved! thanks again @d.b HubertL

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `rollApply` from package `rowr`

```
rowr::rollApply(data, fun=c, window=3, align="right")
[[1]]
[1] 130

[[2]]
[1] 130 156

[[3]]
[1] 130 156 872

[[4]]
[1] 156 872  23

[[5]]
[1] 872  23  67

[[6]]
[1] 23 67 98

[[7]]
[1]  67  98 104
```